# Java compare database schema with JPA entities at run time

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How to compare database schema with JPA entities at run time using Eclipse Link

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear exactly what you are after, but I use a session customizer to run validation when required:

```
public class ValidationCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {
     public void customize(Session session) {
          IntegrityChecker checker = new IntegrityChecker();
          checker.catchExceptions();
          checker.checkDatabase();
          session.setIntegrityChecker(checker);
     }
}
```

And then add it to the persistence unit:

```
properties.put("eclipselink.session.customizer", "packagename.ValidationCustomizer");
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(NAME, properties);
```

Comment: I want to check if 
* all tables in persistence unit in database 
* all columns in persistence unit in database
* all tables in database in persistence
* all columns in database in persistence

Comment: Check if what, they exist? Try the above.